# Windows batch file - check if JAVA_HOME contains java 7

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, java-7

Is there a way to determine in a windows batch file if a `JAVA_HOME` environment system variable contains Java 7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have tagged your question as [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), I assume you want to do this in a batch file.

Batch file to check this

```
@echo off
"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\java -version:1.7 -version > nul 2>&1
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto found
echo NOT FOUND
goto end

:found
echo FOUND
:end
```

I have just made the batch file print FOUND if the java in %JAVA_HOME% is java 7 or print NOT FOUND if it's not java 7. You can tweak the batch file for your needs.

java -version:1.7 returns a success(0) to the shell if it's java 7. Else it returns a failure (non-zero). You can use `ERRORLEVEL` to check the return value and determine what the previous command returned.

Comment: Interestingly enough - that didn't work for me - until I changed the line to
"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\java -version:1.7 -version > nul 2>&1

Comment: @hawkeye I don't have 1.7 currently installed, so I tried the above (with -version:1.6) against & just extrapolated it 1.7 Anyway, will update my answer. With 1.6, ERRORLEVEL is 0 with or without the 2nd -version.

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd and check were JAVA_HOME points:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to detect installed java version, you should parse the result of "java -version". JAVA_HOME is only installation directory